# Monte Carlo: Importance sampling on unit disk and in higher dimensions

Tags: matlab, optimization, random, sampling, montecarlo

I'm am working on an assignment on importance sampling in Monte carlo. The following code was provided:

```
    clear dim=2;power=3;const1=?;const2=?;N=10^5;

       X=(rand(dim,N).^power);
       %creates a random sample of N vectors of dimension 2
       %the coordinates of these vectors are not uniformly
       %random: they have P(coordinate<a)=a^(1/3)

    Density=prod(const1*X.^(const2)); 
    Sample=(sum(X.^2)<1);
    %count the number of vectors < 1 

    ISSample=Sample./Density*4; 
    aM=mean(ISSample);
    bM=std(ISSample); 
    [aM-1.96*bM/sqrt(N),aM+1.96*bM/sqrt(N)]
```

The question is two-fold:

How to find the constants, and how to make it work in higher dimensions. 
I have been working on this for ages, but I can't seem to get a grip on the importance sampling. I would expect as the samples are generated in the third power, that constant 2 would be in the third power as well, but this gives confidence intervals with imaginary numbers. Any help on which direction I should take would be greatly appreciated!

Regards, 
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I won't write any code now, my Matlab is too rusty. But here is the general idea.

Your sampling is uniform on a unit disk and done with rejection method. Actually, it could be split into two problems. One is sampling of the point on the unit circle. Second, is sampling of the radius in accordance to the some power law.

Let's start with radius sampling. It is quite easy to see, that due to Jacobian in 2D case radial distribution is proportional to `r*dr` and could be sampled as

```
r = sqrt(U(0,1)); % or
r = pow(U(0,1), 1/2);
```

In case of 3D due to Jacobian PDF is proportional to `r^2*dr` and could be sampled as

```
r = pow(U(0,1), 1/3);
```

In general nD case there is an obvious conclusion that radius could be sampled as

```
r = pow(U(0,1), 1/n);
```

Ok, now we should select point on the unit sphere in case of 3D or on the unit hypersphere in case of higher dimensions, multiply it by radius and get point uniformly inside the sphere/hypersphere

For sampling the point on there sphere I would advice to pick Marsaglia method from

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html

For sampling the point on there hypersphere I would advice to pick similar method from

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html